# ARM "str" assembly equivalent

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, porting

I'm porting a code to use ARM GCC 4.6.4 , previously compiled with 3.3.3.
I have the following instruction ( mem.c ):

```
/*For ARM based machines with gcc/gas 3.3.3*/

#define GET_RET_ADDR(file)  asm("str lr, %0" : "=g" (file) : /* no inputs */ ")
```

which yields:

```
Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up
```

when compiling with 4.6.4.

What will be the equivalent ARM Assembly function? I have tried:

```
asm("mov %0,lr" : "=g" (file))
```

but it failed.

Comment: Huh? The compiler doesn't change the instruction set - `str` is still `str` regardless of what toolchain you use. The constraint is probably the issue (`g` is rarely if ever an appropriate constraint for ARM), but without knowing how this is used (i.e. what gets passed for `file` and whether it's always the same type) we can't really say. I _would_ suggest that implementing this as a macro is part of the problem - a type-safe inline function would be a lot more robust.

Comment: complete call is :
char *file;
GET_RET_ADDR (file);
Could it be libc being upgraded ?

Comment: Apparently this macro tries to get the return address. `gcc` happens to have a `__builtin_return_address` function for that, I would recommend to use it.

Comment: Change to `asm("str lr, [%0]" : "=r" (file))` or `asm("str lr, %0" :: "p" (file))`.  The `__builtin_return_address` is different as sometimes the return address is not stored in `lr`, but somewhere on the stack frame; in fact it maybe an improvement, but only you have the complete code.

Comment: Thanks all for you help .